# How to pull changes from one branch to another branch through git

Tags: git, github

I have one repository with multiple branches in GitHub. I have changes in one branch. How can I pull these changes from the working (development) branch to the master branch using putty?

Comment: Have you tried `git merge developBranch master`

Comment: If you're just starting out, then you might find [this free course](https://www.udacity.com/course/how-to-use-git-and-github--ud775) helpful.

Comment: on development branch do you try to ... `git pull origin master`?

Comment: `putty` is absolutely useless in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone a specific branch to a new local folder :

```
$ git clone -b my-branch git@github.com:user/myproject.git
```